# Does Rcpp::stop() require an extra unprotect?

Tags: r, rcpp

When terminating early with `Rcpp::stop()`, is it necessary to unprotect early in the below example?

I'm aware that I could have rewritten this using IntegerVector without the protect and unprotect calls, but I suppose I'm asking this for my own understanding as the function produces no stack imbalance warning with or without the first `UNPROTECT`.

```r
library(Rcpp)
cppFunction('SEXP with_protect(){
          SEXP out = PROTECT(Rf_allocVector(INTSXP, 10));
          int *p_out = INTEGER(out);
          if (true){
          UNPROTECT(1);
          Rcpp::stop("early termination");
          }
          p_out[0] = 10;
          UNPROTECT(1);
          return out;
          }')
cppFunction('SEXP without_protect(){
          SEXP out = PROTECT(Rf_allocVector(INTSXP, 10));
          int *p_out = INTEGER(out);
          if (true){
          Rcpp::stop("early termination");
          }
          UNPROTECT(1);
          return out;
          }')
with_protect()
#> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos): early termination
without_protect()
#> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos): early termination
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: If you want to write plain C code (to further your understanding) I recommend you go all the way and a) do not use `cppFunction()` (or `sourceCpp()` which add `Rcpp` headers, try `verbose=TRUE to see) and b) do not use `Rcpp` functions either.

Comment: Thank you for the comments and no disrespect intended, though appreciate the honest response.